# link_to in helper with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  name
  content_tag(:i, "", :class => "icon-plus icon-white")
end
```

but it only shows me the icon specified by `i` (twitter-bootstrap css) and not the text in `name`, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The return value of the block becomes its content. Only the last line is being returned.

You must concatenate the two strings together with `+` to produce a single return value:

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  name + content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-plus icon-white")
end
```

You'll need to use `html_safe` to prevent the content of your tag from automatically being HTML encoded:

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  name + content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-plus icon-white").html_safe
end
```

Speaking from personal experience with Twitter Bootstrap, I know you will need a space between `name` and `content_tag`:

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  name + ' ' + content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-plus icon-white").html_safe
end
```

Alternatively, if you are inside an ERB template, you can output both values with `<%=`:

```
<%= link_to( ... ) do %>
  <%= name %>
  <%= content_tag( ... ) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if im doing this my button shows: `foo<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>`

Comment: You can use HTML safe to mark your strings as not requiring HTML encoding.

Comment: I did test it with html_safe too and it didnt work, but this works: `link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  (name + ' ' + content_tag(:i, "", :class => "icon-plus icon-white")).html_safe
end` if you want you can update your answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I'd consider:

1) The whole content of the `link_to` block needs to be sanitized.

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  (name + content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-plus icon-white")).html_safe
end
```

2) Can we expect input to be `nil`?

Things will break if we call `html_safe` on a `nil` object. Use `raw` if there is a chance this could happen.

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do
  raw(name + content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-plus icon-white"))
end
```

[This](http://www.tigraine.at/2012/08/23/when-to-use-raw-and-when-to-use-html_safe) is a good read on the subject. [My blog post](http://www.aharails.com/intermediate/6-link_to-helper-with-a-block/) presents an interesting application of this.

Answer (score 1):

For those that use font-awesome or something else it might not show the icon. But this solution worked.

```
link_to :sort => column, :direction => direction do
   "#{title} #{content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-chevron-up") }".html_safe
end
```