# link_to tag not including all divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a link to tag which should wrap around all the content within it, but currently it's not doing that. It's wrapping around the code until it hits another div with a rails query inside it?

**index.html.erb**

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="widget" >

<%= link_to post do %>

  <div class="image b-lazy" data-src="<%= post.image %>">
  </div>

  <div class="caption">
    <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
    <p>by <%= post.affiliate %></p>
  </div>

  <!-- LINK TO TAG ENDS HERE FOR SOME REASON --> 


  <div class="caption-top">
    <% post.categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= link_to category_path(category) do %>
        <div class="tag <%= category.name %>"><%= category.name %></div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

<% end %>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Jonathan

Comment: According to the rules of html, you can't put an `a` tag inside another `a` tag.  I'm not sure if Rails is smart enough stop you doing this, but either way you shouldn't try to do it since it will be broken even if Rails lets you do it.  Why do you want all of that whole chunk of html inside a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You are using `link_to` inside another call to `link_to`. That is probably not what you want.
- The result of a block will be what you return from a block, normally the last line. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317067/link-to-in-helper-with-block) for a solution.